# HttpWebRequest needs to wait 5 seconds to work properly in PUT method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to use an API and I don't have any problems with GET and POST but PUT isn't working. I tried with a lot of different examples and finally by chance I discovered that waiting more that 5 seconds (with 5000ms it is not working and with 5100ms it does) it starts working properly. But why is that happening? And how can I avoid this? 5 seconds for each registry update is to much waiting and I really don't understand why POST works well without waiting and PUT needs 5 seconds to work.

Here I put the method that I am using with the `Thread.Sleep(5100)`. As I said without this line when I make `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();` gives me an error.

```
public void call(string url, object jsonObj)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(urlSplio);
                // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
                request.Method = "PUT";
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["User"], "WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]");

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // Get the request stream.
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();

                Thread.Sleep(5100);
                // Get the response.
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                // Display the status.
                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the content.
                Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
                // Clean up the streams.
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to rewrite the response stream code

Take a look at this walkthrough on MS [MS walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx)

```
private byte[] GetURLContents(string url)
{
    // The downloaded resource ends up in the variable named content. 
    var content = new MemoryStream();

    // Initialize an HttpWebRequest for the current URL. 
    var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    // Send the request to the Internet resource and wait for 
    // the response. 
    // Note: you can't use HttpWebRequest.GetResponse in a Windows Store app. 
    using (WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse())
    {
        // Get the data stream that is associated with the specified URL. 
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Read the bytes in responseStream and copy them to content.  
            responseStream.CopyTo(content);
        }
    }

    // Return the result as a byte array. 
    return content.ToArray();
}
```